# Wordpress website cannot be found after accidentally changing site URL

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean

I changed my Wordpress website site URL prematurely and now it tells me [Not found The Requested URL was not found on this server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNLpd.png) I've been struggling with this and trying to find a fix but everything I've done has not fixed it. I've gone into the config file to update the URL, define the URL, you name it, I've done it. So I'm pretty desperate at this point and any help would be appreciated.

P.s I'm also running the server off of a Digital Ocean droplet. So I haven't been able to access the DB through MyPhpAdmin.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the fix!!**

When the site URL changed so did the root directory. The root directory added another folder to the path. So it looked something like this `var/www/html.old/html`.

Apache was still trying to access the site through `var/www/html`.

So I adjusted the file path and boom! Apache was able to make the connection and the website is now showing.

To get to the apache folder it was `/etc/apache2/site-available/`. I was then able to nano into the 000-default.conf file and adjust the file path through there.

Answer (score 1):

To change the WordPress site URL you need to do it manually as you can’t do it from your WordPress admin panel. There are two ways to do that:

**Method 1** - Change WordPress site URL by editing `wp-config.php` file. This is the easiest way;

Add the following code to the end of `wp-config.php` file and save the file.

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.com');
define('WP_HOME', ' http://www.example.com');
```

*Change `www.example.com` with your site domain.

**Method 2 -**
Please try to change the URL from PHP MY ADMIN > select your database > goto wp_options and change the URL

- Using FTP/ SFTP , or your web-host’s cPanel or whatever file management application your host provides, access phpMyAdmin on your host, then find your DB, there check the wp_options Table (Note: The table prefix of wp_ may be different if you changed it when installing), and make sure site URL field and home field are correct.

Comment: What if I was to purchase cPanel for my current droplet? I do not have cPanel by default on the droplet. And I do not want to run commands in the FTP MySQL from fear of breaking things. 

Would the license for the cPanel be enough to access my current websites DB?

Comment: You don't need to Cpanel when you can access the WordPress files in the Digital Ocean droplet. If you can Access wp-config.php then you can edit the page like Method 1.

Comment: I found the fix!!

When the site URL changed so did the root directory. The root directory added another folder to the path. So it looked something like this `var/www/html.old/html`.

Apache was still trying to access the site through `var/www/html`.